# Beating one's head against the wall / a brick wall

Tags: idioms, expressions, phrases

Dictionaries say that the idiom "beating one's head against the wall" means:

> To attempt continuously **and fruitlessly** to accomplish some task or achieve some goal that is or seems **ultimately hopeless.**

As you see here in the definition, the expression includes the connotation of a useless action.

There is an Example in the Freedictionary as below:

> Some people are never going to agree with you on this, so **it's no use** beating your head against a wall trying to convince everyone.

I think the segment **"in no use" is redundant here, while the idiom encompasses the meaning.

P.S. Although to me, this expressions means: **to try so much to do something** and it doesnt have the connotation of "a useless action".

I wonder if you could explain that to me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some people are never going to agree with you on this, so it's no use beating your head against a wall trying to convince everyone.

I think the sentence makes perfect sense, and "it's no use" is a necessary part.

As you have said, beating one's head against the wall is trying so much to do something (fruitlessly). So, it's no use trying so hard to do something that is ultimately hopeless.

Of course, if we say "it's no use trying... trying to convince everyone," it sounds unnatural because of 2 "tryings" in one sentence. However, with the idiom it all sounds fine.

Note that "it's no use" is used to talk about something fruitless - it's the function of the phrase:

> It's no use crying over spilled milk.
>
> It's no use asking me about it, because I don't know anything.
>
> It's no use trying to stop her - she is unstoppable.

Comment: Thank you @Enguroo, but according to what you mentioned, I think it is somehow a synonym for "beating the air". Do you agree?

Comment: @A-friend I agree, and it's no use beating the air - because it's pointless. ;-)